# Block button press for X seconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, time, timer

I have a project where I need the button that starts the function to be "blocked" for 3.5 seconds after the last click. I mean the button should be still displayed just as it was, but on click it should not react in any way for 3.5 seconds. Here is the sample that displays current time on button click:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The user should be able to click on the button (and run the function) several times without needing to reload the page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does "displayed as it was" mean that disabling the button is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    document.getElementById("button").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 3500)
}
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFxfZ/)